# SelectNodes not scoped to the Element

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

If I call SelectNodes on an XmlElement, and pass  XPath query such as this:

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlElement.SelectNodes("//OtherNode");

The nodes list will be for all the OtherNode elements in the document not just the ones from xmlElement.

I seem to recall that this is by design, and for a good reason, but I can't remember what that good reason was, nor how to get around it.

Answer (score 10):

Just add a `dot` to the beginning of the `xpath`. The `dot` selects the current node:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlElement.SelectNodes(".//OtherNode");
```

Comment: A simple explanation of "why" is that it's like with file paths - `/foo/bar` is an absolute path, where the leading `/` means "start from root"; `foo/bar` is a relative file path, which can also be written `./foo/bar`. Similarly with XPath, and there it applies to both `/` and `//` - so leading `/` always means "start from root node in the tree to which the current context node belongs".

Comment: Because he wants to consider all descendants, and not just immediate children?